# Need to hide a selected element based on conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, global-variables, variable-declaration

I have drop down menu with various options

- New
- In Progress
- Ordered
- Not Ordered
- Completed
- Cancelled

I have a form which I need to hide the ETA row when status is new, then enable it for any other status. This is what I tried:

```
var progress, ordered, unordered, completed, cancelled, reg, high, user, trimUser, etaDate, etaRow, etaHour, etaMinutes;

function initiate() {
    //declaring necessary variables
    declaration()
}

function declaration(){
    //Declaration of variables for status changes
    sNew = $("option[value='New']");
    progress = $("option[value='In Progress']");
    ordered = $("option[value='Ordered']");
    unordered = $("option[value='Unordered']");
    completed = $("option[value='Completed']");
    cancelled = $("option[value='Cancelled']");

    //Declaring variables for priority changes
    reg = $('input[value="ctl00"]');
    high = $('input[value="ctl01"]');

    //Declaring current user using SPServices 
    user = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentUser({
    fieldName: "Name",
    debug: false
    });

    //Declaring variables for ETA field manipulation
    etaRow = $("nobr").filter(function () { return $.trim(this.childNodes[0].nodeValue) === "ETA"; }).closest("tr");
    etaDate = $('input[title="ETA"]');
    etaHour = $("[id$=DateTimeFieldDateHours]");
    etaMinutes = $("[id$=DateTimeFieldDateMinutes]");

}

function hideETA(){
    //hide ETA options
    etaRow.hide();

    if(sNew.not(:checked)){
        alert('CP1');
        eta.show();
    }
}
```

So the way I tried to do it was by initially hiding it (because new is the default), then when it's anything but new, show it.

**EDIT:**
I think I have it solved, this is how I did it after some help from @Richard with my if statement and selectors:

```
function setETA(){
    //Hide, Display and Disable ETA based on stages         
    if(sNew.is(":checked")){
        etaRow.hide();
    }else if (progress.is(":checked")){
        //do nothing, should be already showing
    }else{
        etaDate.attr("readonly","true").css('background-color','#F6F6F6');
        etaHour.attr("disabled","disabled");
        etaMinutes.attr("disabled","disabled");
    }
}
```

Comment: Just right off the bat, change `if(sNew.not(:checked))` to `if(!sNew.is(":checked"))`.  Add the quotes and use the .is()...

Comment: Done. Just wondering though, what's the .not() do then, I thought it was the same thing

Comment: So what's your actual (relevant) HTML?

Comment: `.is()` returns a boolean. It's a simple, efficient check.  `.not()` returns a duplicated subset of the original input.  For example: `$("li").not(".selected").css(...)`.  The `.not()` might work (with the quotation marks) but it's not doing what you think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2 possibility:

- Display = none
- Remove the option

For the display method: http://jsfiddle.net/r7gLU/1/

```
// Hide the Option
var opt = $('option[value=New]');
opt.css('display','none');
if( opt.parent().val() == 'New' )
    opt.next().attr("selected", "selected");

// Show the Option
var opt = $('option[value=New]');
opt.css('display','');
```